# Parameterizing a common template

Tags: java

I need to execute the same set of statements but with a different name of the field each time. I was wondering if there is a better way to write this?

```
int returnCode = collectValue("empName", record);
if(returnCode <0)
{
return false;
}

returnCode = collectValue("empNum", record);
if(returnCode < 0)
{
return false;
}

returnCode = collectValue("empSalary", record);
if(returnCode < 0)
{
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two primary ways I can think of to change this:

1. Iterate over an array

   ```
   String[] fieldNames = new String[]{ "empName", "empNum", "empSalary" };
   for (String field : fieldNames) {
       if (collectValue(field, record) < 0) {
            return false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Boolean short-circuiting

   ```
   boolean returnFalse = collectValue("empName", record) < 0 || collectValue("empNum", record) < 0 || collectValue("empSalary", record) < 0;
   if (returnFalse) {
       return false;
   }
   ```

I would personally recommend the first version, as the second version creates a long statement and is a bit more difficult to both read and debug.